# link_url is truncating URL after 100 character in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We are using GA4 (Google analytics 4). We have one issue in **link_url** EVENT PARAMETER KEY under **file_download ** event name. It is truncating character after 100 length.

Any solution to get the full url ?

I tried to create custom event to show the link url but it is not showing the exact url.

Comment: It looks like that is normal GA4 behavior. See if this GTM solution explanation is helpful: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/track-file-downloads-with-google-analytics-4/#caveats